# az login returns error "Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution"

Tags: networking, dns, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nameservers, az

I was doing `az login` from WSL of my windows machine. Then it gives an error:

```
Please ensure you have network connection. Error detail: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /common/oauth2/token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f401d135630>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))
```

I hope this is a DNS issue.
So I checked `/etc/resolv.conf` of WSL:

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, remove this line.
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver fcc0:0:0:ffff::1
nameserver fcc0:0:0:ffff::2
```

**192.168.1.1 is the default gateway.**

There are the results of some commands I tried:

```
$ ping 192.168.1.1

PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.                                                                                                                                          
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.351 ms                                                                                                                                   
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.888 ms                                                                                                                                   
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.883 ms  

$ dig 192.168.1.1

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.3-Ubuntu <<>> 192.168.1.1                                                                                                                                          
;; global options: +cmd                                                                                                                                                                       
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached 

$ nslookup 192.168.1.1

;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

These commands also give an output that indicates an issue.

```
Ping google.com
dig google.com
```

All these commands( or its alternatives) work from the Windows command prompt works correctly.

I found a **workaround** here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/91543/apt-get-update-fails-to-fetch-files-temporary-failure-resolving-error

It says that I should add the followinng line to /etc/resolv.conf. If I try it like this, it works.

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8 
nameserver fcc0:0:0:ffff::1
nameserver fcc0:0:0:ffff::2
```

After this, the `ping google.com` and `dig google.com` works fine. But I can see that the nameserver it uses to resolve is `8.8.8.8`.

If I connect to VPN, it adds our own nameservers to /etc/resolv.conf and after that, there is no problem in resolving the URLs. Once the VPN is disconnected, the issue arises again.

**Note:**

There were no issues like this before.
Last day we changed our router in order to use a new ISP's connection and after that, the issue occurs.
Other machines in the same network don't have this issue.

Why this occurs and How can I properly fix this issue of WSL?

Why only one machine in our network can ping, but can't dig to the default gateway?

**Update:**

I can see that there are two entries that are marked as default in routing table:

```
 $ ip route show table all | grep default                                                                                

 none default via 192.168.0.1 dev wifi0 proto unspec metric 0                                                            
 none default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth6 proto unspec metric 0
```

Comment: I came here with the same error but not for the same reason, however the posted workaround to add google DNS `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to `resolv.conf` fixed my issue